# play framework 1 + eclipse: no syntax check

Tags: eclipse, playframework-1.x

I created an play framework project with Version 1.2.5. After hat i ran Thema eclipsy Commando and opened the project Wirth eclipse.

Auto completion works but there is no Syntax check for the java files. For example, if i do not write a ; at the end of a command there is no mistake shown at the border of the editor on the left.

I think it is because that the root folder is no source folder in eclipse. Can i change that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the project, not create a new project.  http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm

> You can use the Import Wizard to import an existing project into
>   workspace.
>
> - From the main menu bar, select   File > Import.... The Import wizard    opens.
> - Select General > Existing Project into Workspace and click Next.
> - Choose either Select root directory or Select archive file and click    the associated Browse to locate the directory or file
>     containing the    projects.
>        Under Projects select the project or projects which you would like to    import.
> - Click Finish to start the import.